# Passing many alists in a loop without actually listing them one by one

Tags: alists

The following function add string associations if matches are found within a collection of alists.  Currently I am listing the alists `andromeda-assoc-tablet-N` one by one.  Can one manage to this without actually listing them individually because I have many of them (have got 57 alists)?  Perhaps apply `mapcar` then pass the actual list to the loop.

Have been scrutinising why I cannot get the following implementation plan that uses `mapcar` to work.

```
(dolist (aggr (list (mapcar #'andromeda-construct-assoc-tablet
                            (number-sequence 1 57))))
  (setq rplc (cdr (assoc word aggr)))
  (unless (null rplc)
     (add-to-list 'nscrip
         (replace-regexp-in-string word rplc word))))
```

Here is the detailed description

```
(defvar nscrip '())

(defconst andromeda-assoc-tablet-1
  '( ("OrycteropusAfer" . "Aardvark")  
     ("VicugnaPacos" . "Alpaca") 
     ("MyrmecophagaTridactyla" . "Anteater") ))

(defconst andromeda-assoc-tablet-2
  '( ("Dasypodidae" . "Armadillo")  
     ("TaxideaTaxus" . "Badger")
     ("Beaver" . "Beaver") ))

(defconst andromeda-assoc-tablet-3
  '( ("LynxRufus" . "Bobcat")
     ("LepomisMacrochirus" . "Bluegill")
     ("RangiferTarandus" . "Caribou") ))

(defun andromeda-shorten-word ()
  "Shorten word at point according to specific rules."

  (interactive)

  (let* ( (bounds  (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
      (word (downcase (buffer-substring (car bounds) (cdr bounds))))
      (rplc "") )

    (goto-char (car bounds))
    (add-to-list 'nscrip word)
    
    (dolist (aggr (list andromeda-assoc-tablet-1
                        andromeda-assoc-tablet-2
                        andromeda-assoc-tablet-3))
      (setq rplc (cdr (assoc word aggr)))
      (unless (null rplc)
         (add-to-list 'nscrip
             (replace-regexp-in-string word rplc word)))) ))
```

Thus if `word` is `LynxRufus`, then `nscrip` is `Bobcat`.

I have made the following function

```
(defun andromeda-construct-assoc-tablet (n)
  "Return value of symbol `andromeda-assoc-tablet-N', an alist of
paired string elements."

  (symbol-value (intern (format "andromeda-assoc-tablet-%d" n))))
```

My scheme is to use something like

```
(mapcar #'andromeda-construct-assoc-tablet (number-sequence 1 57)
```

that I can pass to `aggr` in function `andromeda-shorten-word`.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show a minimal example of one of your input alists and also a minimal sample of what you need `nscrip` to look like afterwards.

Comment: Having lots of almost-identical variable names that vary only by an index number is a "code smell"; you should probably revisit your design. If you know you will always have exactly 57 alists, no more no less, then you might consider an array of 57 alists instead. If you sometimes have more, sometimes less, then a list of alists is probably better.

Comment: Currently 57 but could use more or less depending on task.  Will put a minimal example.

Comment: The setup does not have a `code smell` problem, but necessitates from requirements of supportable code.  Do not worry about the psychological smell.